# How can I access a var inside of a structure to count the number of items listed in the var's array?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need help being able to display in a string format within the each sections title of the table view the number of listed (Cells) inside the sectionData array. Which the sectionData is listed as a var inside of a structure(cellData).

```js
import UIKit

struct cellData
{
    
    var opened = Bool()
    var title = String()
    var sectionData = [String]()

    
}



class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableViewData = [cellData]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Monday, September 10, 2018", sectionData: ["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Tuesday, September 11, 2018", sectionData: ["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Wednesday, September 12, 2018", sectionData: ["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Thursday, September 13, 2018", sectionData: ["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Friday, September 14, 2018", sectionData: ["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3"])]
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return tableViewData.count
    }
    
//
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if tableViewData[section].opened == true
        {
            return tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1
        }
        else
        {
            return 1
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
     let dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1
        
     if indexPath.row == 0
     {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
        
        return cell
     }
        

     else
     {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]
        
        return cell
     }
    }
//
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true
        {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)// play around with this
        }
        
        else
        {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)// play around with this
        }
    }

//

}
```

[Swift 4: Structured array to display in tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euweD.png)

[iPhoneX Build: Display of Sections in tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIQK1.png)

[iPhoneX Build: Display of Sections and Cells in tableView when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsz3k.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way i can think of. You would need two extra variables - one for **get**ting the count, another for the count appended title. If you don't mind building the string to be displayed yourself, you can *skip* the second one.

```
struct cellData {
    var opened = Bool()
    var title = String()
    var sectionData = [String]()

    var count: Int {
        get {
            return sectionData.count
        }
    }
    // This variable is for convenience
    var titleWithCount: String {
        get {
            return "\(title) (\(count) Cells)" // Format it as you require
        }
    }
}
```

Use the `titleWithCount` variable when populating the section title.

Comment: Thank You! I now understand the concept behind getting and returning the count value. My only question for you is how to write or format the variable structure of cellData to use  "titleWithCount" in my viewDidLoad section. I want to display the number of cells listed below in the sections title next to the title string. for example: "Monday, September 10, 2018 (3 Cells)".

Comment: @MichaelEdlin i've explained that in the last line. Check edit.

Comment: Nevermind! I figure it out once I saw your last statement to use titleWithCount to populate the section title. I had to change [indexPath.section].title with titleWithCount. Thank You!